# Animate images on VB C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, animation, graphics

I am looking to animate a set of images and perform different actions dependent on which images are showing.

There are 13 images (ball1, ball2, ..., ball13), once the series reaches 'ball6' I need to a graphic to be created from the centre of the image. After that has happened it will need to pause/hold/wait for maybe 2 seconds and then follow onto 'ball7' (this is why a .gif hasn't been used). The animation needs to continue until the end (ball13) then create a different graphic and finally pause again for 2 seconds before restart the cycle...

I am poor with graphics and I am looking to learn this field so as much information as possible is appreciated.

***Edits***
Sorry, using WinForms at present, willing to convert for simplicity as this is start of newest project.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? WPF? Winforms?

Comment: Answered in edit. :)

Comment: Well, if you can, switch to WPF. The capabilities of WPF will make your life MUCH easier if the need for animations grows. You'll find plenty of documentation about WPF animations on Google.

Comment: Still looking for help on this, I'd much prefer some guidance as I have never used WPF and have limited time. Anyone able?

Comment: This is too broad for a specific answer here, especially as there's no code to work on.

Comment: It isn't, is it? Just need to know what code would allow an image to load and swap images until one array of images is done the wait for a timer and repeat for next set of images, I just don't know how to render this..

Comment: This is not a code-service site... You'll have to walk your way through WPF and come back with specific programming questions, with your code. BTW if you really have limited time and you don't know WPF, this may not be a good solution, you should stick to Winforms if you know it well.

Comment: No, I agree I don't want code on a platter I just want suggestions on methods. For example, using WPF I tried it, struggled with graphics on it as its layout is on another level. WinForms would be my choice but the problem those is rendering transparency without frame skip..

Comment: I understand, but we can't give you more WPF guidance until you learn more of it, and we can't give you WinForms guidance until you post your code. Post your WPF or Winforms code once you have something that partially works and ask a specific question.

Comment: Okay, well I have restarted on WinForms and will update you when I have all code ready. Thanks you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I loaded the application again, re-imported images using WinForms as that supports .gif files. You can simply switch between the .Image file for each .gif at any point with one line of code; using a bool if it fits nicely which it did for me.

**This isn't correct code, just draft.**

```
bool picswitch = false;
   _For Loop here_
        {
            if (picswitch = false)
            {pictureBox1.image (*.png)} 

            else if (picswitch = true)
            {pictureBox1.image (*.png)} 
        }
```